# Inductors in AC circuit

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, electric-current, voltage, inductance

We know that the current varries in an a.c. circuit if we connect an inductor to the circuit when the current is maximum the inductor oppose the current and tries to decrease the current and when current start to decrease it tries to increase the current  so why the current doesn't remain constant in the circuit

Comment: You said it, it's an AC. The driving source which provides the Alternating Voltage has to do work against the impedance offered by the inductor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inductors will oppose a change in current. Therefore it is incorrect to say that the inductor will oppose the current when it is at a maximum, since the current is not changing when it is at it's maximum value. You are correct when you say the inductor will try to increase the current in one direction when it is decreasing. But just because it opposes it does not mean it will stop that change or reverse it.

A crude analogy we can make is trying to pull an object through a viscous medium. Just because the drag force opposes the force you are applying to the object does not mean that it will cause it to move at a constant velocity.

Plus like a.b. said, you have stated it is an a.c. circuit, so it can't be constant if something is driving the current to not be constant.